# Why is IIT "unmotivated"?

Tags: consciousness, philosophy-of-mind, theory-of-mind

I'm trying to understand [Searle's reply to Tononi and Koch's objections](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/2013/03/07/can-photodiode-be-conscious/) to Searle's characterization of their Intergrated Information Theory (IIT) of consciousness.

Although I do understand why IIT is problematic, both from [Searle's original review](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://virgil.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/searle.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi2wvboo9PNAhVP92MKHVS5BI8QFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNEc0X7oXzOJ5BcDV1LkxJcgUEI-GA&sig2=R9kGgMSHa8KX-n1kiVRjVA) and from [Thagard's alternative proposal](http://cogsci.uwaterloo.ca/Articles/thagard.two-theories.consc&cog.2014.pdf), I don't understand his reply.

Specifically, what does Searle mean by IIT being "unmotivated"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the reason he considers it unmotivated is that he would like to see a theory that can explain the [hard problem(s) of consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness).  In that final paragraph where he argues that the theory is unmotivated, he points out that (in his opinion) IIT seems to do nothing to explain why there is something *it is like* to be conscious from a subjective viewpoint (i.e., [qualia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia)).

My two cents is that I can see Searle's point; it is not clear how IIT would explain these aspects even if it is otherwise completely successful.  On the other hand, calling it "unmotivated" seems a bit unfair; perhaps it would still be useful for other purposes, for example judging whether patients in a hospital are (likely to be) conscious.  A more reasonable claim would be that it is not well motivated by trying to resolve the hard problems of consciousness, but may be well motivated by other goals.